# Creating objects with a for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, object-reference

I need to create several contacts to populate an arrayList. When I try to create and Object of type Contact inside a for loop, it keeps returning and Object that has the same reference through all of them. Therefore, when I change the first contact, every other contact in the array changes. What am I overlooking?

```
 String[] split = ret.split(";");
 this.clear();
 for(int j = 0; j<split.length/6;j++)
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            for(int i =j*6; i<split.length;i++)
            {
                if(i%6==0){contact.setFirst(split[i]);}
                else if(i%6==1){contact.setLast(split[i]);}
                else if(i%6==2){contact.setCell(split[i]);}
                else if(i%6==3){contact.setWork(split[i]);}
                else if(i%6==4){contact.setEmail(split[i]);}

            }
            this.add((E) contact);
        }
```

Thanks for evrything.

Comment: You might want to add why you think it is the same reference. "new Contact()" is guranteed to produce a new object instance. BTW: the inner loop is not needed.

Comment: He uses the inner loop because every contact is build with 6 fields. I know it could be done differently, but that is how he did it.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for(int i =j*6; i<split.length;i++)
```

should be:

```
for(int i =j*6; i< (j+1)*6;i++)
```

Basically you were looping between j*6 and the length of the array split, every time. So this way, in every loop you kept seting the fields to different values until the last one. So everyone of your contact was set with the values of the last one.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't do it for me. I'm 99% sure this is memory references though, since changing one value changes all of them...

Comment: You may have more problems in other part of your code. That is from what we can see.